# Lightning custom button like Javascript button on classic

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom-button, lightning-apps, action

we have some requirements for which we need to build-up buttons like "javascript button" enabled for Classic version of SF.

If I would like to reproduce the same behaviour in lightning the only way in which I can do this using "Quick action", can't I?

Otherwise, I might use lightning component embedded into a visualforce page, but I've a problem while refreshing the record detail view (it seems you should use only window.reload() or something similar to do that), so I won't be able to get field updated into the view as long as I won't refresh the page.

Do you have any suggestion regarding this issue?

Comment: I don't understand what is missing from the quick action solution, which should be best practice, please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: I've been reading a bit of quick action, the only thing I would like to avoid is to show every time I click the action the modal box.

Comment: I understand, it is not nice, but you can make it disappear by entering `$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();`. You will still see it for 1 second, but I think it is a better solution than all other workarounds.

Comment: window.reload might take longer because it refreshes the whole page with the lightning logo and all. What might be done is after the field update is done, you can call the method responsible for fetching all the data again. This will refresh your view without refreshing the page.

Comment: @ItaiShmida yes I added this method, it's not a good thing for the UI, but It seems to be the only way to fix this issue so far.

Comment: @MohitArora what do u mean with "method responsible for fetching all the data again"?

Comment: @FabioMaturo What I meant by that is, there must be a method that returns all the records when the component is loaded and you display them on the component. After calling the custom refresh action, you can call that method again with the arguments that you were passing initially.

Comment: @MohitArora It doesn't work like this my component, It's a quick action and I don't need to display any records, it's not a custom lgt component for record detail. My component does only an update on the record got by Id with the "force:hasRecordId", after updating that fields in the callback I do refresh all view and after that I close the quick action with the function wrote above.

Comment: @FabioMaturo So in that case, you must have an attribute of the sObject type of the record you are updating, when you click the save button you must be calling an apex method that updates the record. After that, return the same record from the method that you have just updated, use the action.setCallback method in lightning, set the returned value to the attribute of yours and the updated record will reflect with the new value.